# Canonical MaaS utilisation on large machines

Tags: server, maas, canonical

Apologies if I'm asking something that's been covered before - my search didn't bring anything up.

From what I have seen on Canonical MaaS on bare metal, we provision the whole server with a single OS image, like Ubuntu, right? But what if the server's so big that it's almost a waste to use it as just one server? Without bringing a hypervisor into the mix, is there a way we could slice up that bare metal into multiple machines using Canonical MaaS, and/or some other software?

Thanks in advance
Tom

Answer (score 0):

MAAS currently supports different hypervisors to achieve what you are describing here. LXD is the reccomended one, you can read more here https://maas.io/docs/how-to-use-virtual-machines#heading--MAAS-VM-hosting and then here https://maas.io/docs/how-to-set-up-lxd